# Error: attempt to index a nil value (upvalue 'cfg')

Tags: mysql, lua, fivem, grand-theft-auto

The money in my FiveM server doesn't show up, and I can't buy anything either and I think it has to be related to this. In my database, I see that there is supposed to be money in my balance.

```
[          script:vrp] SCRIPT ERROR: @vrp/modules/money.lua:269: attempt to index a nil value (upvalue 'cfg')
[          script:vrp] > fn (@vrp/base.lua:643)
```

Code in money.lua:269 (265-274)

```lua
-- money hud
AddEventHandler("vRP:playerSpawn",function(user_id, source, first_spawn)
  if first_spawn then
    -- add money display
    vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"money",cfg.display_css,lang.money.display({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getMoney(user_id))})})
    vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"bmoney",cfg.display_css,lang.money.bdisplay({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getBankMoney(user_id))})})
        vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"Dogecoins",cfg.display_css,lang.money.Dogecoins({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getDogecoins(user_id))})})
        vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"VenomCoins",cfg.display_css,lang.money.Diamante({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getVenomCoins(user_id))})})
  end
end)
```

Code in base.lua:643 (643-647)

```lua
        TriggerEvent("vRP:playerSpawn",user_id,player,first_spawn)
      SetTimeout(config.load_duration*1000, function() -- set client delay to normal delay
        Tunnel.setDestDelay(player, config.global_delay)
        vRPclient.removeProgressBar(player,{"vRP:loading"})
      end)
```

Config of money.lua (vrp/cfg/money.lua)
https://paste.to/en/raw/6104059872228

Comment: You using `config` in your `base.lua` but `cfg` in `money.lua` are these supposed to be separate config libraries, if so where is `cfg` defined?

Comment: you mean the config of money.lua? if yes, i thought it wasn't that relevant, but i'm gonna add it anyway

Comment: yes the config called `cfg` in `money.lua`, the reason it is relevant is the error you have shown states that you are attempting to index `cfg` and it is a `nil` value. so something is going wrong with the definition of `cfg` or it is out of scope where the handler is defined

Comment: i've changed it, is it better now?

Comment: That `cfg` file is not valid lua syntax